# Couldn't refresh the JFrame

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, timer, event-dispatch-thread

I have a simple `JFrame` which contains a `JButton` and a `JLabel`.

```
public class Frame extends JFrame {
    public Frame() {
        initComponents();
        this.frameExample = new JFrameExample(jLabel1,jPanel1);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void initComponents() {
        //this method only place the button and the label to the frame, it is auto-genereted by Netbeans tool.
    }

    private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        frameExample.count();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Frame().setVisible(true);
    }

    JFrameExample frameExample;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
}
```

And I have a simple class that gets the `label` object by constructor, and sets some values to the label with `count()` method.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class JFrameExample {
    public JFrameExample(JLabel label, JPanel panel) {
        this.label = label;
        this.panel = panel;

        setFrameRefreshTimer();
    }

    public void setFrameRefreshTimer() {
        frameTimer = new Timer (100,new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                label.revalidate();
                label.repaint(); 
                panel.revalidate();
                panel.repaint();  
                System.out.println(label.getText());//doesn't print anything
                }
            });
    }

    public void count() {
        frameTimer.start();

        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            label.setText(i + "");

            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }

        frameTimer.stop();

    }
    private JLabel label;
    private JPanel panel;
    private Timer frameTimer;
}
```

The problem is, I want to see the numbers when the `count()` method calls the `label`'s `setText()` method. But the frame doesn't refresh. At the end I only see the number `10`. I don't see the other numbers.

I used a timer, but it doesn't help. Am I using the timer wrong? Is there any other solution? I thought about `multithreading` but I couldn't make it work. If anyone could help me with this problem, I will be grateful.

**NOTE:** I simplify my problem with this example, so the solutions which contains changing the constructor parameters or something like this won't provide me a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repeat the timer using [setRepeat(true)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html#setRepeats%28boolean%29) method and break the loop after repeating 10 times via calling `stop()` method inside the `actionPerformed()` method.

Sample code:

```
private int counter = 0;
private Timer timer;
...

timer = new javax.swing.Timer(500, new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        counter++;
        if(counter==10){
            timer.stop();
        }else{
            label.setText(counter + "");  
        }
    }
});
timer.setRepeats(true);
timer.start();
```

#### Note:

Don't use `Thread.sleep()` that sometime hangs the whole swing application instead try with [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) that is most suitable for swing application.

Read more [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Comment: +1 but `timer.stop()` is more intuitive than `break;`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there anyway to call label.setText(counter + ""); outside the timer and see the label's change.

Comment: what is the problem in calling it from inside the timer?

Comment: If you want to update the label after specific delay then it has to be called from timer.

Comment: In the main problem I will update a progress-bar. And I need to set the value of the progress bar from a different place where i get the value of the bar.

Comment: Actually I don't need a delay, i put the sleep for just that i can see the number changes. Because without it i think i wouldn't able to see the changes.

Comment: you have to use timer to see the number changes after a delay. As I told you you should not use `Thread.sleep()` in Swing application. Just keep the reference of the progress bar and update its value.

Comment: Ok, after a second thought I think, I can make a variable and I can change the value of this variable where I need to change the progress bar value, and in timer, I set the value from this variable.

Comment: You can call some setter method that will update the progress bar status or there are lots of ways to achieve it.

Comment: @Braj Thanks for the better solution. +1

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution, maybe this answer will help other people.

I use `Thread` instead of `Timer`.

Changed the method  `jButton1MouseClicked()` with this.

```
private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    thread = new Thread() {
          public void run() {
              frameExample.count(thread); //sent the thread to close it.
          }
        };
    thread.start();
}
```

Change a little bit the method `count` for closing the thread.

```
public void count(Thread thread) {
       for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            label.setText(i + "");

            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }

       thread.stop();
    }
```

With these changes I am able to see the counting from the `label`. And you don't need to call `label.setText(i + "");` from a `Timer`.